# Select item in a dropdown list and change the word

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for badly explaining this in just the title.

What I want to do basically feels like a slider. It should look like this:
http://screencast.com/t/9q5uQlYBoViD (bootstrap).

However, the drop down title should change according to the selection. 
For example; I click on the dropdown, I click on the second item, and the dropdown title (in the image called "Dropdown 2") changes and becomes the name of the item I clicked on.

My goal with that is to build something like:
Viewing content for : Weather
The user can change from Weather to Sport, News etc. in which I'll fetch the right content from the DB etc.

From bootstrap's docs, it doesn't tell how I can do this. How can I?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what code you've tried, but you can do this by handling the dropdown click event.
For example, this will set the content of the first item when the dropdown is clicked:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Here is a demo: 
[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/62811)